# How can I test a function of a function component that uses React.useState() using jest enzyme testing?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I have a function component that uses React.useState() to manage the state of a drawer modal. I want to test the function the changes this state using jest enzyme, but I cannot call it's state function because it's not a class component.

The code I wish to test is below:

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    drawerOpen: false,
});

function toggleDrawer(boolean) {
    setState({ ...state, drawerOpen: boolean });
}
```

```
<Button
       id="openDrawer"
       onClick={() => toggleDrawer(true)}
       style={{ margin: spacing.small }}
       >
       <AddIcon />
       {buttonText}
</Button>
```

And this is what would've worked if it was a class component:

```
it("should open the drawer on button click", () => {
        wrapper.find("#openDrawer").simulate("click");
        expect(wrapper.state("drawerOpen")).toBetruthy();
});
```

And yes, it should remain a function component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it will be helpfull:
Here is an mock util, that is basically a function that is going to accept state and return a tuple

```
export const setHookState = (newState: {}) => jest.fn().mockImplementation((state: {}) => [
   newState,
   (newState: {}) => {}
])
```

Then, in test, you just use it like this:

```
import { setHookState } from 'utils/test'
import { ComponentWithHook } from './ComponentWithHook'
import { NeededComponent } from './NeededComponent'
const reactMock = require('react')
describe('ComponentWithHook component', () => {
  it('should render itself', () => {
    reactMock.useState = setHookState({
        data: [],
        isFetching: false
    })
    const wrapper = shallow(<ComponentWithHook/>)
    expect(wrapper.find(<NeededComponent>).exists()).toEqual(true)
  })
})
```

Info from this source: [here](https://medium.com/@yevgen4/way-to-test-react-usestate-hook-with-jest-and-enzyme-acfeb1b4f8aa)

Comment: I understand exactly nothing of this, could you adapt this to my situation? Maybe then I can follow you rather than this very generic version.